# How to get Azure Mobile service data into Grid View in Asp.net(C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, datagridview

I m maintaining Azure Mobile service data in Azure.I will need for Access that Azure mobile service data into web page.

so,i m created some web page in Asp.net(C#).how i can get Azure Mobile service data into my Grid View in Asp.net?

but,i get data into normal html table..follow my code

### WebForm1.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" >

<table id="DBDataPlaceHolder1" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="auto-style1">Code</th>
                <th class="auto-style1">Name</th>
                <th class="auto-style1">Descrption</th>
                <th class="auto-style1">Sort</th>
                <th class="auto-style1">Enable</th>
                <th class="auto-style1">Action</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>                    

 <asp:PlaceHolder id="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

    </table>
</form>
```

### WebForm1.aspx.cs

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                RetrieveAzureAsync(sender,e);

        }

   async private void RetrieveAzureAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             IMobileServiceTable<BranchList> BranchTable = client.GetTable<BranchList>();
            StringBuilder htmlTable = new StringBuilder();
            // This query filters out completed TodoItems and
            // items without a timestamp.
            List<BranchList> items_list = await BranchTable
               .Where(branchitem => branchitem.Enable == true)
               .ToListAsync();


            int size = items_list.Count();
            if (size > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                    htmlTable.Append("<tr>");
                    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + items_list[i].BranchCode + "</td>");
                    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + items_list[i].BranchName + "</td>");
                    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + items_list[i].Descr + "</td>");
                    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + items_list[i].Sort + "</td>");
                    htmlTable.Append("<td>" + items_list[i].Enable + "</td>");
                    htmlTable.Append("<td> <i class='icon-large icon-edit'>   <a href='' OnClick='Button1_Click' runat='server' class='icon-large icon-trash'></td>");
                    htmlTable.Append("</tr>");
                }
                htmlTable.Append("</table>");

                PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = htmlTable.ToString() });



            }
        }
```

### OutPut:

[image]

how i can get Azure Mobile service data into my Grid View in Asp.net?please any one help me

Comment: Please add your web page code.

Comment: @MrMush Thanx for reply.Which code??

Comment: The web page you have created.

Comment: @MrMush i have add my data into normal html table..bt,i can not get this data into grid view

Comment: Raja, in order for us to help you, please edit your question and add the problematic code that does not work to your question. It is near impossible to help without seeing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MrMush please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i Found way for get Azure mobile service data into Grid view.

```
List<BranchList> items_list = await BranchTable
           .Where(branchitem => branchitem.Enable == true)
           .ToListAsync();

            MyGridView1.DataSource = items_list;
            MyGridView1.DataBind();
```